# Responsive design: meta tag loading

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, metatag

I'm looking to get this construction, I know it's not possible but i'm looking for an alternative way.

```
@media all and (min-width: 480px) {
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
 maximum-scale=1" />
}
```

So basically I need this `<meta />` tag to only be active on screens larger then `480px` in width.

Can this be done with standard HTML or is there a jQuery sollution?

Comment: Check out what they're doing here: http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jquery-media-helpers/sample.html You can see in the source how they return the true/false value for the media query you want.

Comment: Please don't limit the users' ability to zoom the page (maximum-scale=1)

Comment: @steveax thx, i deleted that bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS won't be able to insert a META tag like this (you could target IE with IE specific comments but I doubt that helps you).

You can however inject this tag dynamically using JavaScript:

```
//set a flag so the meta tag doesn't get loaded more than once
var metaLoaded = false;
$(window).on("resize.my-meta", function () {

    //check if the meta tag has already been loaded, if not check the viewport width
    if (!metaLoaded && $(window).width() >= 480) {

        //the viewport width is at or greater than 480, so add the meta tag to the DOM
        $("head").append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />');

        //set flag so we don't add the meta tag twice
        metaLoaded = true;
    }
}).trigger("resize.my-meta");//this runs the resize event handler to setup the initial state
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5GxNH/

Comment: @kevinius When you say things like that you should qualify what you mean. What browser were you using? What `didn't work` about it? Did you see any error messages? Where were you using the code (JSFiddle or on your own page)? I ask these questions because it definitely adds a meta viewport tag when necessary in the browsers I tested (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari). If you inspect the DOM after the code runs you will find a meta viewport tag only if the window for the page is greater than or equal to `480px`.

Comment: Jasper, It does indeed add the meta tag, however, it doesn't work on retina displays, like the iphone 4 because it measures the device width, not the css width. If i use your code the meta will always be added because the device width of the iphone 4 is 960px.

Comment: @kevinius The iPhone 4 has a screen resolution of `640x960px`. So yes the viewport meta tag will always be added because you've set a break-point too low. Also, as far as your question is worded, my answer works (it adds a viweport tag to the DOM for a specific viewport width). If you need more help with something else (it sounds like you're having problems between landscape and portrait orientation) then I suggest creating another question (or more likely just find one already answered).

Comment: Jasper thx, is there a way to get the css width, instead of the device width.

Comment: @kevinius `$(window).width()` gets the viewport width, in pixels. For an iPhone 4 it would render `640px` in portrait orientation and `960px` in landscape. You can use those values as break-points. Other than that, I'm not sure what you're asking.